# snap "heroku" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

Tags: 16.04, heroku

I execute the following commands to install heroku:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

This error occurs:

> snap "heroku" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

I'm trying to fix it this way:

```
//.bash-profile
[[ -s "/snap/bin/heroku" ]] && source "/snap/bin" 
//.bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin"
//.zshrc
export PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin"
```

But the error remained.

Help fix please.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do
`sudo snap remove --classic heroku`

and then reinstall with
`sudo snap install --classic heroku`